# Is it possible to let the access point handle the firewall rather than the main router?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, dd-wrt

I have two routers: one is ADSL, the other one is a broadband, and my line from the ISP is ADSL. So, I did use the ADSL router as the main one that handle the connection to the internet, and used the broadband one as a access point. Everything is working fine, but my question is:

- I flashed the broadband router(the AP) to DD-WRT and I want to use its features. So, can I disable all the features from the main router and let the AP handle everything (firewall)? I want every computer to go through the AP and let it do the firewall when it wants to connect to the computer.

Is that possible?

The DD-WRT provides lots of feature that are more far better than the stock firmware, but in my situation I can't use it as a main router since I have ADSL connection.

Comment: Sure just connect the two routers.

Comment: I did that of course :) , but unfortunately everything is forwarded to the main router. i did tried (for example) to block access to the internet using mac filter, even that its not working. so, from it i relaysed that any thing (or rule) i will put it will not applied here.